# Remove column space in table created with d3

Tags: html, css, d3.js, whitespace, css-tables

I would like to remove column space in a d3 table. I need to remove everything to the right of the red line in the image below and ensure the data only fit inside the div. It appears to add extra space than what is required. Thanks for your help

[image: Remove to the right of red line]

The following outlines the code I have use. Please see html and css code below.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="map">
        <svg></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="box-plot">
        <svg></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="table"></div>
      <div class="line-chart">
        <svg></svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

/* And the css*/

```
.map {
  grid-area: map;
}

.map-path {
  /* fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.01); */
  /* stroke: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); */
  /* stroke-width: 1px; */
}

.map-path.counties {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.map-path.catchments {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.map-path.aquifer {
  /* stroke: rgba(0,200,0,0.5); */
  /* stroke-width: 0.5px; */
}

.map-path.gwrockunit {
  /* stroke: rgba(200,0,0,0.5); */
  /* stroke-width: 0.5px; */
}

.map-path.selected-basemap-polygon {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.box-plot {
  grid-area: box-plot;
}

.table {
  grid-area: table;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: Courier;
  /* max-width: 400px; */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background: #eee;
}
th {
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: s-resize;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 3% center;
}
td, th {
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
}

.line-chart {
  grid-area: line-chart;
}

.grid-container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'map map box-plot table'
    'map map line-chart table';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container div {
  background-color: white;
}

.grid-container div svg {

  /* This makes it so the grid does not resize when the SVG is added */
  position: absolute;
}

.basemap-selector-widget {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.basemap-selector-widget rect {
  fill: white;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.basemap-selector-widget text {
  font-family: sans;
  alignment-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

Comment: I edited your question's title and removed the [tag:d3.js] tag from the tag list because there is no such as thing as a *"D3 table"*. That's just an HTML table, the fact that it was created with D3 should not matter for the answer. However, if the D3 code has anything to do with the problem here, you can edit your question adding the tag again, but please also share the D3 code.

Comment: Ok, fair point, however the table was created using d3.js so I would like to include the tag if possible to see anyone else has had this same problem. I will try isolate the d3 code that creates the table and share it. Thanks

Comment: style `.table` refers to a `div`, a `div` is by default always 100%, how can we set the `border-collapse` for a `div` it will be overridden by the browser default style for a `table` tag. In my Chrome browser the table is minimal size without `border-collapse`, Do I have to apply the class `table` to a table?? Just show a filled HTML (with dummy data)

Answer (score 0):

override this rule: `.table{ width: 100%; }` with something like `width: auto`

Comment: Unfortunately - this just gives the first image in this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928736/remove-white-space-in-d3-table/51928990?noredirect=1#comment90821932_51928990]

Comment: Hi,Do you mean replace `.table{ width: 100%; }` with `.table{ width: auto; }` as this does not work for me either? thanks